# Confused over a python concept as a beginner who has only started learning cs. Any help would be really appreciated

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I've been stuck with something which has really halted my learning process as someone who has just started learning cs

Suppose I get an output score every turn in an iteration and the score for every turn is a random number ranging from 1 to 15

Now for every turn I want to print whether the score jump in that respective term is the biggest score jump in ALL of the turns played yet. It won't print anything if it isn't the biggest jump in score yet

I just can't seem to wrap my head around executing something like this and it has put everything I have to learn after it to a halt

#This is the function where I try to define the highest point for the score in this function-

```
def highest_gain(previous_value, highest_point) :
    def say(score0) :
        if previous_value == 0:
            print ('Biggest gain by player0 yet with',score0,'points!') 
            return highest_gain(score0, score0) 
        gain = score0 - previous_value
        if gain > highest_point:
           print('Biggest gain by player0 yet with',score0,'points!') 
           return highest_gain(score0, gain)
    return say
```

#This is the function for updating the score every turn and then call it with below-

```
    while n > 0:
          score += random.randint(1, 15)
          f = say(score)
          n -= 1
    return score 

score0(6,0,highest_gain(0,0))
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated . This has been bugging me for a few days now. I just can't seem to understand why the values inside of highest_gain can't remain updated after every turn they are executed.

Comment: Well, you have a function nested within a function.  Although that's possible, it's almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: That is actually because I'm currently (self) learning higher order functions. So this specific question needs me to implement this using them.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask, but I suspect what you need is not what you asked for.

```
import random

highest = 0

def score0(n):
    global highest
    score = 0
    for i in range(n):
        bump = random.randint(1, 15)
        if bump > highest:
           highest = bump
           print('Biggest gain by player0 yet with',bump,'points!') 
        score += bump
    return score

score0(6)
```

Comment: Thank you! But right now I'm self learning higher order functions now and this is a tidbit of what one of the question requires me to do from that chapter.